# Python-Flask for loop breaks with a return statement

Tags: python, flask

I have this problem in my program using Python Flask Framework that when I use a `return` it doesn't do the `for loop`. I tried to move my `return` statement in inside the `for loop`, aligned in `if` statement but always have the same problem.

I searched many times about this problem, I always saw that `return` statement should be after the `for loop` not inside.
This is what I did, but it's still the same.

```
if chk_log_dir == True:
    ftp = ftpconnection()
    ftp.cwd(ftp_directory + region[0])
    files = ftp.nlst()

    for file in files:                            
        if idDate in file:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + file , open(save_path + file, 'wb').write)

    ftp.close()
    return redirect(url_for('mainpage'))
```

Comment: Are you sure `files` is not `None`?

Comment: @metmirr, Well absolutely yes, if I'll not put the `return` statement, it will collect files from `FTP`. But if I'll put it, it will stop collecting files and go to mainpage.

Comment: just comment logic with `ftp` and make sure that `open(save_path + file, 'wb').write` works fine. path is exists, file was created etc..

Comment: @DanilaGanchar .. just a clarification of what do you mean comment logic with `ftp`? I'm sure that the `open(save_path + file, 'wb').write` works fine.

Comment: @KarlGuevarra hmmm. Looks strange. Did you try to debugging with breakpoints?